# Python share logging across subclasses

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am trying to find a best practice approach to sharing logging across classes/subclasses/modules. The following classes could be in the same file or spread out across packages/modules.

E.g.

```
-- A.py  
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(someName)

-- B.py  
class B(A):
  ...

-- C.py  
class C(B):
  def foo(self):
    self.logger.info('Hello from C!')
```

Now in this case, the entire class hierarchy shares the same logger instance, as set by the base class.

Is that a good practice? Or should I set a global variable at the top of each .py file like:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

The first approach seems more OO, and avoids doing anything on module import (onlyon object creation), whereas the second approach creates a different logger seen by each class with a name reflecting the module it is in.

The other advantage of the first case is I can set custom logging options on the single instance at it will work across all the classes, whereas in the second case it would only work if each logger name extended the parent/base logger name, e.g. logging.getLogger('A.B.C'). However these classes need not be in the same package or package hierarchy so that may not always make sense.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: If you are going for a better practice I found https://github.com/Delgan/loguru to be very easy to use. Not sure if it helps but hopefully it'll be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty subjective, but the approach I have taken before is to have `logging` settings configured in a `commons` or `utils` module which can be imported by different files. Each file will instantiate their own `logger`. I think it is good practice to always do `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` as it really helps with debugging.

Example:

```
-- commons.py
logging.setLevel('INFO')

-- A.py
from commons import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("init")

    def foo(self):
        logger.info("foo")
```

In this example, the benefit is that you have a central place for configurations rather than logging being spread out everywhere. Only downside is the boilerplate of instantiating a new logger every time.